# Eclipse Plugin - How to attach method on action save

Tags: java, plugins

I write a eclipse plugin to format properties.

Can you tell me how to execute a method on the save of the source of the editor?

I want to format properties on save? Can you help me?

I did not find any documentation about it.

Thank you.